# Why restrict browser access to API for html files loaded using the file protocol?

Tags: browser

Below is my source code, I did three tests on this source code. Why are the results different?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button id="getData">getData</button>
      <div id="response"></div>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#getData").click(function () {
                  const apiUrl = "https://api.tianditu.gov.cn/geocoder";
                  const queryParams = {
                      postStr: '{"lon": 116.37304, "lat": 39.92594, "ver": 1}',
                      type: "geocode",
                      tk: "042ea7c9021511c43493a17f09c1bdda"
                  };

                  $.ajax({
                      url: apiUrl,
                      data: queryParams,
                      method: "GET",
                      success: function (data) {
                          $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                      },
                      error: function (error) {
                          $("#response").text("request failed：" + error.statusText);
                      }
                  });
              });
          });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above source code implements requesting data from the specified API and placing it in the div with the id of response after the data request is successful.

- **Test1**: I save it as index.html and double-click the icon, which opens the file in the browser.Then I click the getdata button and it will show that the request failed.
  [image about requesting failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XNgv.png)
- **Test2**: In vscode, I use the plugin(live server) open the index.html. I get the response successfully.
  [image about getting the response successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsdgX.png)
- **Test3**: Enter the API directly in the browser navigation bar and successfully return the response.
  [image about entering the API directly in the browser navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPqVs.png)

**Why can't I successfully send a request to the server when opening an html file directly? Why does the server need to add this restriction?**